# calling reduce on list of akka http routes yields compilation error (no implicit value for parameter join)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka, implicit, akka-http

Given the following routes

```
val route1: PathMatcher[Unit] = PathMatcher("app")
val route2: PathMatcher1[String] = PathMatchers.Segment
val route3: PathMatcher[Unit] = PathMatcher("lastSegment")
```

I can easily define

```
val resultingRoute: PathMatcher[Tuple1[String]] = route1 / route2 / route3
```

getting the expected type (PathMatcher[Tuple[String]]).

But creating the route programmatically like in

```
val routeDef = List(route1, route2, route3)
val resultingRoute = routeDef.reduce((a,b) => a / b)
```

will not compile, giving me

> could not find implicit value for parameter join: akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.TupleOps.Join[_1,_1]

Furthermore, the inferred type of resultingRoute is

```
PathMatcher[_ >: Unit with Tuple1[String] with join.Out]
```

I'd really appreciate any hint giving me some indication of what I'm doing wrong here or how this could be resolved.

For completeness, here's my imports:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{PathMatcher, _}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Where is `routeDef` defined?

Comment: Updated the question adding the routeDef assignment, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your `routeDef` list is actually heterogeneous, the compiler infers its type to be `List[PathMatcher[_ >: Tuple1[String] with Unit]]`.

Given that, the `(a: PathMatcher[L])./(b: PathMatcher[R])` method needs implicitly a `TupleOps.Join[L, R]`: [akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatcher](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/master/akka-http/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/server/PathMatcher.scala#L25). It cannot be inferred from `PathMatcher`s types in your `routeDef` list.

---

If you are willing to use [`shapeless`](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) you can then work on heterogeneous lists (called `HList`s in this context) easily:

```scala
import shapeless._
```

```scala
val routeDef = route1 :: route2 :: route3 :: HNil
```

```
object join extends Poly {
  implicit def casePathMatcher[A, B](
    implicit t: akka.http.scaladsl.server.util.TupleOps.Join[A,B]
  ) = use((a: PathMatcher[A], b: PathMatcher[B]) => a/b)
}
```

```scala
val resultingRoute: PathMatcher[Tuple1[String]] = routeDef.reduceLeft(join)
```

Comment: Your answer encouraged me to give this another try, but I was not able to create the implicit TupleOps.Join value... I wonder if this approach could be generalized at all, being difficult already for such a simple case. I created a gist with a little test case, if somebody has an(other) idea: https://gist.github.com/evandor/075cad445712a1144f3d55744516eceb. If  this is not suitable for a (more) generic approach, it does not make much sense for me to proceed that way...

Comment: Updated answer to add a suggestion (and an example) on how to manage heterogeneous lists using shapeless and use of `reduceLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your reduction expression.

**1. Reduce & Associativity**

By using `reduce`, rather than `reduceLeft` or `reduceRight`, you are saying that

```
(a / b) / c === a / (b / c)
```

Because a simple reduce does not give any certainty to the ordering.

I don't think path matcher combinations are associative.

**2. Reduce & Unit**

Another issue with using reduce is that it is undefined for an empty list, therefore the result is always ambiguous.  Almost always a better option is `reduceOption`.

Comment: You're right, that makes perfect sense. Still, using "routeDef.reduceLeftOption((a,b) => a / b)" or "routeDef.reduceLeft((a,b) => a / b)" will give me compilation error stated above.